# Avoid tiny url in Twilio SMS

Tags: android, ios, twilio, deep-linking

I am implementing deep linking in my android app. In some scenarios I [send SMS using twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). However Twilio changes the link which are sent in SMS to tiny url which results in no deep linking as url scheme has changed.

Is there any way to force Twilio not to replace the links with tiny url with in the text message range (140 characters).
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can turn off automatic link shortening in your [Account settings](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings). Scroll to the bottom of the page and you will find the option.

[image]]